# mysql database connectivity issues

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection

I was following this guide: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-a-login-page-with-php-and-mysql/28656 to create a login page. I followed everything to the letter but when I uploaded the two files (login.html and connectivity.php) to my public_html folder of my godaddy linux shared hosting server and attempted to test it out, I was met with a blank page when I navigated to: mydomainname.com/connectivity.php.  Now after reviewing the code within connectivity.php, my suspicion was that my mistake lay somewhere in my database setup.  This is what I am referring to:
[image]

I changed the database name "practice" to the actual name of my database that I created through godaddy.  I got a little bit stuck on the "DB_USER" section though.  I added a user to my database through godaddy's mysql application and changed the name "root" to the name I set for the user.  Here is what I'm referring to:
[image]

After I did that I changed the "DB_Password" to whatever I had set for the username's password.  I thought at this point I was done but when I attempted to navigate to the page, it still didn't work.  I know the "DB_HOST" is set to localhost but I wasn't sure what I was supposed to change that to since phpMyAdmin panel stated the following: "Server:localhost" even though I'm using a server.  I added all the tables and users to the mysql database correctly so I really think this has something to do with my configuration. If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that your uploaded files have the appropriate permissions?

Comment: @Abdo Adel  I believe I do, for testing purposes I gave them 777 permisions

Comment: BTW, 'localhost' does not mean your laptop, it means the current host/server (the current machine), so using it at the server is o.k since the script is running on the server and you want to connect to the DB on the same host/server

Comment: @Abdo Adel  Thanks for the info.  That was my suspicion but I'm glad someone was able to confirm that for me.

Comment: BTW again :D, 'localhost' is defined as a constant in the 'hosts' file in any OS as '127.0.0.1' which is the IP of the current machine, If you changed it to another IP then you are making a remote connection to another DB server on another remote machine, that far-away MySQL server should enable the remote connection if you want to do so, just a side note :)